# Mongodb db.dropUser() ReferenceError: is not defined

Tags: mongodb

```
> use mydb
switched to db mydb
> show users
{
    "_id" : "mydb.mydbReadWrite",
    "user" : "mydbReadWrite",
    "db" : "mydb",
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "readWrite",
            "db" : "mydb"
        }
    ]
}

> db.dropUser(mydbReadWrite)
2015-03-29T03:55:52.276+0200 E QUERY    ReferenceError: mydbReadWrite is not defined
    at (shell):1:13
```

I don't understand? I am logged in with a root user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
db.dropUser(mydbReadWrite)
```

instead use:

```
db.dropUser("mydbReadWrite")
```